# What is this spigot shutoff valve called?

Tags: plumbing

tl;dr: what’s the proper name for the valves in the picture?

Below is a picture of the shutoff valves for the two outside spigots/hose bibs in my townhouse which was built in 1995. When open water drips from the knob area.

They look simple enough to replace except I don’t know what they’re called so my searches for replacements have been fruitless. All the terms I’ve tried turn up results for all manner of things that are not those.

Also, what is the the little knob on the right that looks like it has a set screw in it?

[image: two shutoff valves]

Comment: Have you tried removing the little knobs on the sides, cleaning them out and re attaching them?..(turning the valves off first). You might even be able to get replacement knobs at a plumbing store.  The one on the right looks like it's not even on all the way.

Comment: @JACK no, it never occurred to me to do that, I didn’t know what they were for so I ignored them.

Comment: So did you try it?

Comment: @JACK Not yet, I was working on something else when I posted.  I'm going to work on it this weekend when I have time for multiple trips to the hardware store in case things go awry.

Answer (score 4):

I believe they are inline shut off valves.  They look like 1/2 inch pipe size, but picture might be making them look smaller.  Come in different designs, but all work the same.

The little knob is a drain valve that you open after turning off the valve to drain the rest of the pipe when the outside faucet is open.

Comment: Specifically, these are inline "gate" valves. The oldest home I've lived in had these and all the rest had quarter-turn ball valve shutoffs instead.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the side knobs! I’ve always (i.e. the few years I’ve owned the place) closed the valves in winter and opened the spigot. When I get to fixing the valves I’ll see if they even still turn, I get the sense the previous owner (who was also the original owner) wasn’t much into maintenance. @FredricShope thanks for putting a name to those little knobs!

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the compression seal.

Shut off water.

Unscrew the Philips screw holding the handle.

Right under it you will see the compression nut (about 1/2 inch size)

Unscrew it, NOT the valve it self.

[image: nut]

In there is the compression seal that is leaking and that needs to be replaced (mostly o-ring type).

Bring it to the store to find the right size.

I do not know the name for that valve or where to find it, but if you plan to replace the whole valve (instead of fixing the leak) that is another story.

Comment: Is that your own picture?

Comment: @MichaelKaras yes, from my home

Comment: I found it interesting that the compression nut almost looks like it may be plastic.

Comment: @MichaelKaras bad photo ......

Answer (score 1):

In a refinery they are called "block and bleed" valves. They isolate a section of pipe and the small knob permits draining of that section; for example to prevent freezing water bursting the isolated section.